# R - Warnings when using cv.lm

Tags: r, cross-validation

I've tried to apply cv.lm function instead of my own script which performs K-Fold cross validation and though the results are matching the formulas and my own thing, I keep getting warnings when using cv.lm:

"As there is >1 explanatory variable, cross-validation
 predicted values for a fold are not a linear function
 of corresponding overall predicted values.  Lines that
 are shown for the different folds are approximate"

Like I said, it doesn't seemto affect the results; however, I'm suspicious that it might. Thanks for any opinions or advices.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the warning is to the Plot but not the cross-validation itself. It warns you that the plot uses estimated values for other dimensions.